# Case class schema inference treats both option and non option fields as nullable

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I ran a following spark-shell exercise:

```
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.1.0
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_121)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> case class Test(notNullable:String, nullable:Option[String])
defined class Test

scala> val myArray = Array(
     | Test("x", None),
     | Test("y", Some("z"))
     | )
myArray: Array[Test] = Array(Test(x,None), Test(y,Some(z)))

scala> val rdd = sc.parallelize(myArray)
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Test] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:28

scala> rdd.toDF.printSchema
root
 |-- notNullable: string (nullable = true)
 |-- nullable: string (nullable = true)
```

I've read (Spark in Action) that given a case class with Option fields, those not optional should be inferred as not nullable. Is that even true? If so what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues here:

1. Non-optional fields are inferred as non-nullable only for some types (`Int`, `Long`, `Short`, `Double`, `Float`, `Byte`, `Boolean`), and `String` is apparently not one of those; You can see the behavior for `Int` for example:

   ```
   case class Test(notNullable: String,
               nullable: Option[String],
               notNullInt: Int,
               nullableInt: Option[Int])

   val myArray = Array(
     Test("x", None, 1, None),
     Test("y", Some("z"), 2, Some(3))
   )

   myArray.toSeq.toDF().printSchema
   // root
   //  |-- notNullable: string (nullable = true)
   //  |-- nullable: string (nullable = true)
   //  |-- notNullInt: integer (nullable = false) // !!!
   //  |-- nullableInt: integer (nullable = true)
   ```

   this can be seen by inspecting the code in [`org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection.schemaFor`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.1.1/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/ScalaReflection.scala#L674):

   ```
   def schemaFor(tpe: `Type`): Schema = ScalaReflectionLock.synchronized {
     tpe match {
       // ...
       case t if t <:< localTypeOf[String] => Schema(StringType, nullable = true)
       // ...
       case t if t <:< definitions.IntTpe => Schema(IntegerType, nullable = false)
       case t if t <:< definitions.LongTpe => Schema(LongType, nullable = false)
       case t if t <:< definitions.DoubleTpe => Schema(DoubleType, nullable = false)
       case t if t <:< definitions.FloatTpe => Schema(FloatType, nullable = false)
       case t if t <:< definitions.ShortTpe => Schema(ShortType, nullable = false)
       case t if t <:< definitions.ByteTpe => Schema(ByteType, nullable = false)
       case t if t <:< definitions.BooleanTpe => Schema(BooleanType, nullable = false)
       // ...
     }
   }
   ```
2. Apparently there's a different code path for inferring schema if you first create an RDD and *then* convert it into a DF, instead of converting the *local collection* directly into DF - the two behave differently:

   ```
   case class Test(notNullInt: Int, nullableInt: Option[Int])

   val myArray = Array(
     Test(1, None),
     Test(2, Some(3))
   )

   sc.parallelize(myArray).toDF.printSchema
   // root
   // |-- notNullInt: integer (nullable = true) // NULLABLE TOO!
   // |-- nullableInt: integer (nullable = true)

   myArray.toSeq.toDF().printSchema
   // root
   // |-- notNullInt: integer (nullable = false)
   // |-- nullableInt: integer (nullable = true)
   ```